# How to display the Inspect tab in Figma?

Tags: css, web, interface, figma

I opened [figma layout](https://www.figma.com/file/txgFDXUWNCU9yQ2pmIkM6f/NFT-Dark-Responsive-Landing-Page-UI-UX-Design-Free-Download-(Community)?type=design&node-id=0-1&mode=design&t=TiadQsEsOsb0G8GX-0)
.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI6Ew.png)

But on the right, next to the Design and Prototype tabs, the Inspect tab is not displayed.
How to get it displayed?

I want help with the Figma interface.

content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentcontent content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentcontent content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentcontent content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentcontent content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content contentcontent content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to toggle the **</>** Inspect button in the right top corner. Then Inspect tab will become visible.
See this images:

[Inspect tab not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjJon.png)

[Inspect tab visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyPc3.png)